# Programmatically Unmounting drive from Java

Tags: java, macos, unmount

Does anyone knows how to unmount a drive in java in OSx

I am trying to unmount a sdcard from java. I am using java Swing class and the drive gets mounted automatically, but how do I unmount it.

Comment: potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505682/mount-and-unmount-hard-drives ???

Comment: "I am using java Swing class and the drive gets mounted automatically" <-- I very much doubt Swing is responsible for this at all

Comment: ++ to Michael Dautermann. That is the solution you should follow.

Comment: In Java 7 `FileSystem.close()` might imply an unmount. But it is neither mentioned, and neither do I know the availability of Java 7 on OSx.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of mounting/unmounting is not platform agnostic, so it doesn't exist directly within the Java APIs. You will most probably have to issue a command line call to unmount by using `Runtime.exec()`

There *might* be open source libraries available that wrap this exec call for you, but I'm not positive.

Comment: I have a error in Java Swing class while unmounting an SD card. The following works fine with command prompt "umount -f /Volume/ NO \NAME/". Now if I have to write the runtime.exec() by passing the directory path from swing class I can generate the following command, "umount -f /Volume/ NO NAME/". How to work around the problem of space in java

Answer (score 1):

You could call [umount](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/umount.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/umount) using [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29). Of course, this solution is not portable.